# How can I get the node attributes for the Zachary's Karate Club graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, resourceobject

I am referring to the well-known [Zachary's Karate Club Network](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Zacharys-Karate-Club-Network).

In Python, one can do the following:

```
import networkx as nx

pygr = nx.karate_club_graph()
pygr.number_of_nodes(), pygr.number_of_edges()
# (34, 78)

club_labels = nx.get_node_attributes(pygr, "club")
print(club_labels)
# {0: "Mr. Hi", ..., 9: "Officer", ...}
```

So, in Wolfram Language, I do the following:

```
ClearAll[wlgr];
wlgr = ResourceData["Zachary's Karate Club Network", All]["FullGraph"];
wlgr // {VertexCount, EdgeCount} // Through
(* 34, 78 *)
```

So far, so good. But the nodes in `wlgr` do not appear to have attributes. `AnnotationKeys` does not suggest any such key.

Is this an omission in `ResourceData`, or are the node attributes available in a different way?

Comment: "In Python, one can do the following" That is not "Python", but the NetworkX library, which happens to have this data built in. NetworkX is not part of the Python standard library, and is by far not the only library for manipulating graphs in Python.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is not about Mathematica, but about how to obtain a dataset. I would consider this off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zachary's Karate Club Network does not have vertex labels standardly:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachary%27s_karate_club

If a graph has vertex labels

```
g=RandomGraph[{11,19},VertexLabels->Thread[Range[11]->RandomWord[11]]]
```

then you get them like

```
AnnotationValue[g,VertexLabels]
```

> {6->vindictively,3->costing,11->possibility,5->quadrant,8->fridge,7->integument,10->transitivity,9->prescript,4->crabwise,2->grubby,1->teeming}

Although sometimes those labels are vertices themselves:

```
g=ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph","FlorentineFamilies"}]
VertexList[g]
```

> {Acciaiuoli,Medici,Castellani,Peruzzi,Strozzi,Barbadori,Ridolfi,Tornabuoni,Albizzi,Salviati,Pazzi,Bischeri,Guadagni,Ginori,Lamberteschi}